# I cant insert my values into my SQLite table

Tags: android-studio

So I have been working roughly all the Christmas with this, but it seems like I cant actually find a way, I just create this account because of it. So, lets go into the code.

In first stance, I wanna warning the variables and all that are in spanish, but I dont think it will be a problem.

I have been taking a lot of data, its... if I recall correctly 53 or 56 columns in my SQL table or something like. I have been recollecting data through all the app and getting it through each activity by "putExtra". This is for a project for my school, so I have to use SQLite (I would like to use firebase, being honest) so, whatever, lets go into the code, which is the important stuff.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos) {
        //Creamos instancia a nuestra clase de BD
        BaseDeDatos.execSQL("create table datos_personaje (apellido text primary key, nombre text, edad int, genero text, raza text, clase text, " +
                "fuerza int, destreza int, resistencia int, inteligencia int, percepcion int, voluntad int, carisma int, apariencia int, manipulacion int, " +
                "pelea int, atletismo int, robar int, sigilo int, nadar int, montar int, abrirCerr int, resDolorF int, escalar int, evadir int, esquivar int, bloquear int, " +
                "alerta int, supervivencia int, coherencia int, rastrear int, concentracion int, buscar int, esconderse int, resDolorM int, estrategia int, escuchar int, conGeneral int, tasar int, " +
                "mentir int, empatia int, liderazgo int, intimidar int, callejeo int, comercio int, seducir int, protocolo int, convencer int, actuar int, timar int, disfraz int, " +
                "tecnicasHechizos text, inventario text)");
}
```

This is the creation of the table, I would say its alright.

```
public void SQLiteAyuda() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String nombre = extras.getString("nombre");
    String apellidos = extras.getString("apellidos");
    int edad = extras.getInt("edad");
    String genero = extras.getString("genero");

    String raza = extras.getString("raza");
    String clase = extras.getString("clase");

    int f = extras.getInt("principalesF");
    int d = extras.getInt("principalesD");
    int r = extras.getInt("principalesR");

    int i = extras.getInt("principalesI");
    int p = extras.getInt("principalesP");
    int v = extras.getInt("principalesV");

    int c = extras.getInt("principalesC");
    int a = extras.getInt("principalesA");
    int m = extras.getInt("principalesM");

    int pelea = extras.getInt("pelea");
    int atletismo = extras.getInt("atletismo");
    int robar = extras.getInt("robar");

    int sigilo = extras.getInt("sigilo");
    int nadar = extras.getInt("nadar");
    int montar = extras.getInt("montar");

    int abrirCerr = extras.getInt("abrircerr");
    int resDolorF = extras.getInt("resdolorf");
    int escalar = extras.getInt("escalar");

    int evadir = extras.getInt("evadir");
    int bloquear = extras.getInt("bloquear");
    int esquivar = extras.getInt("esquivar");

    int alerta = extras.getInt("alerta");
    int supervivencia = extras.getInt("supervivencia");
    int coherencia = extras.getInt("coherencia");

    int rastrear = extras.getInt("rastrear");
    int concentracion = extras.getInt("concentracion");
    int buscar = extras.getInt("buscar");

    int esconderse = extras.getInt("esconderse");
    int resDolorM = extras.getInt("resDolorM");
    int estrategia = extras.getInt("estrategia");

    int escuchar = extras.getInt("escuchar");
    int conGeneral = extras.getInt("conGeneral");
    int tasar = extras.getInt("tasar");

    int mentir = extras.getInt("mentir");
    int empatia = extras.getInt("empatia");
    int liderazgo = extras.getInt("liderazgo");

    int intimidar = extras.getInt("intimidar");
    int callejeo = extras.getInt("callejeo");
    int comercio = extras.getInt("comercio");

    int seducir = extras.getInt("seducir");
    int protocolo = extras.getInt("protocolo");
    int convencer = extras.getInt("convencer");

    int actuar = extras.getInt("actuar");
    int timar = extras.getInt("conGeneral");
    int disfraz = extras.getInt("disfraz");

    String poderes = extras.getString("tecnicasHechizos");

    String inventario = inventarioText.getText().toString();
```

I get all my data in the last activity, so I can get it into the SQL table:

```
AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "datos_personaje", null, 2);

    SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues datos = new ContentValues();

    datos.put("nombre", nombre);
    datos.put("apellido", apellidos);
    datos.put("edad", edad);
    datos.put("genero", genero);

    datos.put("raza", r);
    datos.put("clase", c);

    datos.put("fuerza", f);
    datos.put("destreza", d);
    datos.put("resistencia", r);

    datos.put("inteligencia", i);
    datos.put("percepcion", p);
    datos.put("voluntad", v);

    datos.put("carisma", c);
    datos.put("apariencia", a);
    datos.put("manipulacion", m);

    datos.put("pelea", pelea);
    datos.put("atletismo", atletismo);
    datos.put("robar", robar);
    datos.put("sigilo", sigilo);
    datos.put("nadar", nadar);
    datos.put("montar", montar);
    datos.put("abrircerr", abrirCerr);
    datos.put("resdolorf", resDolorF);
    datos.put("escalar", escalar);
    datos.put("evadir", evadir);
    datos.put("esquivar", esquivar);
    datos.put("bloquear", bloquear);

    datos.put("alerta", alerta);
    datos.put("supervivencia", supervivencia);
    datos.put("coherencia", coherencia);
    datos.put("rastrear", rastrear);
    datos.put("concentracion", concentracion);
    datos.put("buscar", buscar);
    datos.put("esconderse", esconderse);
    datos.put("resDolorM", resDolorM);
    datos.put("estrategia", estrategia);
    datos.put("escuchar", escuchar);
    datos.put("conGeneral", conGeneral);
    datos.put("tasar", tasar);

    datos.put("mentir", mentir);
    datos.put("empatia", empatia);
    datos.put("liderazgo", liderazgo);
    datos.put("intimidar", intimidar);
    datos.put("callejeo", callejeo);
    datos.put("comercio", comercio);
    datos.put("seducir", seducir);
    datos.put("protocolo", protocolo);
    datos.put("convencer", convencer);
    datos.put("actuar", actuar);
    datos.put("timar", timar);
    datos.put("disfraz", disfraz);

    datos.put("tecnicasHechizos", poderes);

    datos.put("inventario", inventario);

    BaseDeDatos.insert("datos_personaje", null, datos);

    BaseDeDatos.close();
```

And the debugger shows me the next output:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) 
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting table datos_personaje has no column named coherencia (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO datos_personaje(esconderse,sigilo,protocolo,resdolorf,carisma,genero,destreza,inventario,escalar,alerta,liderazgo,raza,rastrear,escuchar,inteligencia,pelea,edad,disfraz,abrircerr,buscar,manipulacion,comercio,evadir,nadar,actuar,resDolorM,bloquear,conGeneral,resistencia,coherencia,mentir,apariencia,estrategia,tasar,montar,esquivar,robar,nombre,fuerza,clase,supervivencia,atletismo,callejeo,apellido,intimidar,timar,tecnicasHechizos,concentracion,voluntad,percepcion,seducir,convencer,empatia) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
```

Comment: First, uninstall the app from the emulator/device and rerun. It's possible that you have added columns to the create statement after the initial table was created?

Comment: I actually did this morning, but still it doesnt work. So I dont know what else to do.

Comment: Just for a test comment out the line that puts a value to this column and retry.

Comment: I dont exactly know what you mean, I have tried by adding some System.out.print so I can see if the data is correct, and it actually is, if thats what you mean

Comment: Temporarily remove the line: `datos.put("coherencia", coherencia);` and check if the row is inserted

Comment: Okey, it worked out, I mean. if I remove "coherencia" from the database and I dont add it to the table; it works... but I dont know what to do so it doesnt fail.

Comment: Once again, uninstall the app and rerun. The db will be recreated and the table with all the columns in the create statement.

Comment: I actually did that 3 times, and still the same, it gives me an error with "coherencia" and only with it.

Comment: Are you sure that the code you posted is the actual code? Did you misspell the name of the column somewhere? Delete **all** references to `coherencia` and **paste** again `coherencia` at every point where it should be. Uninstall the app again. Then open **Device File Explorer** in AS, go to `data/data/` folder.There should be no subfolder for `<packagename>.<appname>`. Then rerun.

Comment: Im totally sure I did. I actually just commented all the "coherencia" field, and tried with a synonim, dunno why, still the same. So I just deleted that column, and now it works... Dunno man, thanks you very much about everything.